# use 2 queries on one model or 1 query and make it toarray method to get other query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to get an associative array for a select input just like the following code below.

```
public function create() {

  // queries the clients db table, orders by client_name and lists client_name and id
  $client_optons = DB::table('clients')->orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->lists('client_name','id');

    return View::make('projects.create', array('client_options' => $client_options));
}
```

However I will also need to get the entire model $clients.

```
public function create() {

   $clients=Clients::all();

   // queries the clients db table, orders by client_name and lists client_name and id
   $client_optons = DB::table('clients')->orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->lists('client_name','id');

    return View::make('projects.create', array('client_options' => $client_options));
}
```

Since I am already getting the entire model in my query, my question is should I use the 2 queries like shown above or is that bad performance/coding? Should I use 1 query and then play with the model to get $client options? (Like shown below) And do I do this with a loop or are there array functions that do it more succinctly?

```
public function create() {

  $clients=Clients::all();
  $clients_array = $clients->toArray();
  $client_options = /*some code to create array('client_name'=>'id') */


    return View::make('projects.create', array('client_options' => $client_options));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the `lists()` function is also available on collections:

```
$clients = Clients::orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->get();
$client_options = $clients->lists('client_name', 'id');

return View::make('projects.create', array(
    'client_options' => $client_options,
    'clients' => $clients
));
```

Comment: Amazing this is just what I was hoping for! I looked in Eloquent/Model but not Collections. The API is not very clear to me obviously.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't worry it will become easier with time ;)